# Webdav url format in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, web8.5, api, webdav

Did webdav url format changed in Web 8.5?
When I am calling folder.LocationInfo.WebDavUrl API the below output it is returning

> /webdav/300%20ABC%20Content%20%28UK%20EN%29/Building%20Blocks/Content/ABC%20TPL%20Content/Qualifications

When I tried with 2013 Core service url it used to return

> /webdav/300%20ABC%20Content%20(UK%20EN)/Building%20Blocks/Content/ABC%20TPL%20Content/Qualifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think anything specific to Webbdav url is changed in Web 8.5.
Probably underlying framework is handling url encoding a bit differently.
If you do Url decoding of both  Webbdav paths, you would see two identical strings.

Comment: I also recall, during a recent upgrade, that we had some questions on encoding in other areas so I agree that it looks like the underlying framework was changed (perhaps to catch additional characters).

Comment: That is correct, behavior of Uri.EscapeDataString(urlString) method was changed in .NET Framework 4.6.2. See more details in section ".NET method Uri.EscapeDataString(urlString) has changed behavior" in the release notes:
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-8D684619-4A50-412C-AA87-F80F1CEC79D7

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I see these encoded in my test system also. From what I understand of WebDAV, encoding these shouldn't cause an issue. I presume both values function the same?

**UPDATE:**
I understand that parenthesis' are classified as sub-delimiters (W3C) so I wonder if they need to be treated differently as part of a URL as with being part of a set of URL Parameters.

Point taken on the pain of doing a direct comparison of file content post upgrade during a file comparison - I guess you'd have to change you checker to account for specific (non-impacting) encoding differences.

Comment: Agree with you Shahid, Those will fail if we try to do string compare, same issue i have faced while migrating custom page from 2013 SP1, Thought it may be helpful so posted question.